# How to apply both import and provided scope to maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a java maven project X which depends on project Y built by other team. That team provide us with new versions of y.jar. We wanted to dynamically load y.jar.

So, we provided path to y.jar in our project X and project X loads y.jar from that path whenever new version is available. We have specified dependency of project Y in project X's pom with provided scope (so that y.jar wont get bundled inside x.jar).

But then this does not include dependencies specified in project Y in project X. And during run time, we get NoClassDefFoundError error for those classes included in Y's dependencies.

How can I include project Y's dependencies in project X? Usually we import dependencies of other pom with import scope. But I have already specified project Y with provided scope. (Note that x.jar is fat jar and contains all dependencies specified in X's pom.)

What could be best approach to manage dependencies in this scenario. Should y.jar be fat jar?

Answer (score 0):

If your scope for Y is marked as provided then yes Y should be on the classpath and be a fat jar especially if the POM is available and has its dependencies listed.  If you are still getting NOCLASSDEFFOUND, I would explore the y.jar - I would assume its POM is faulty ie declaring dependencies not included in the jar. If Y is not a fat jar or its POM is faulty then you need to explicitly exclude its dependencies and then add them as a compile time dependency. Possibly shading them in. You can use exclusion statements under dependencies.

Read about that here
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Personally, I hate relying on derived dependencies and usually explicitly declare them in my POM.  If they are provided by Y then I would scope them as provided, otherwise scope as compile and ensure they are shaded into my jar.